# org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection

Tags: hibernate

**Exception Trace:**

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
at com.jwt.hibernate.dao.UserDAO.addUserDetails(UserDAO.java:27)
at com.jwt.hibernate.controller.UserControllerServlet.doPost(UserControllerServlet.java:29)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=sagar
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
... 28 more
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=sagar
```

From your exception I see that you dont have the jdbc driver jar in your classpath. Download the SQL JDBC jar and place it in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

while your question (or lack of it) is considered unclear i will try to help:

if you are developing in a local environment you should download a jdbc driver jar and add it in your class path .

if you are developing in remote server environment you should ,in addition to adding the driver to the class path , put the driver in the WebContent/Web-Inf/bin/ folder of you project.

after those steps you should be able to overcome this exception.
good luck.